# Rails: Dropdown list value submission nil

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, radio-button

This is my `view`. There are 3 radio button which user can select either one. When I select `Hourly` for example, it will show the `#send_to_one`.

It works well which show the dropdown list but when I submit the value of dropdown list becomes `nil`.

```
<div id="send_to">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :package %><br>
    <%= f.radio_button :package, 'Hourly' %>Hourly<br/>
    <%= f.radio_button :package, 'Daily' %>Daily<br/>
    <%= f.radio_button :package, 'Monthly' %>Monthly<br/>
  </div>
  <div id="send_to_one">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :day %>Hourly<br>
      <%= f.select(:day, [['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6'],['7'],['8'],['9'],['10'],['11'],['12'],['13'],['14'],['15'],['16'],['17'],['18'],['18'],['20'],['21'],['22'],['23']],{include_blank: "-select-"}) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="send_to_two">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :day %>Daily<br>
      <%= f.select(:day, [['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6'],['7'],['8'],['9'],['10'],['11'],['12'],['13'],['14'],['15'],['16'],['17'],['18'],['18'],['20'],['21'],['22'],['23'],['24'],['25'],['26'],['27'],['28'],['29'],['30']],{include_blank: "-select-"}) %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#send_to_one").hide();
    $("#send_to_two").hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(event) {
        if($(this).val() == 'Hourly') { 
            $("#send_to_one").show();
            $("#send_to_two").hide();
        } else if($(this).val() == 'Daily'){
            $("#send_to_two").show();
            $("#send_to_one").hide();
        } else{
            $("#send_to_one").hide();
            $("#send_to_two").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `nil` because both `select` dropdown are being sent as part of the post request.

One way to solve this, is disabling one of them when you hide its container. Change the javascript for something like:

```
$(function() {
    var $one = $("#send_to_one");
    var $two = $("#send_to_two");

    $one.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
    $two.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(event) {
        if($(this).val() == 'Hourly') {
            $one.show().find("select").attr('disabled', false);
            $two.hide().find("select").attr('disabled', true);
        } else if($(this).val() == 'Daily'){
            $two.show().find("select").attr('disabled', false);
            $one.hide().find("select").attr('disabled', true);
        } else{
            $one.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
            $two.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

According to your comment, check this:

```
$(function() {
    var $one = $("#send_to_one");
    var $two = $("#send_to_two");
    var $three = $("#send_to_three");

    $one.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
    $two.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
    $three.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(event) {
        if($(this).val() == 'Hourly') {
            $one.show().find("select").attr('disabled', false);
            $two.hide().find("select").attr('disabled', true);
            $three.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
        } else if($(this).val() == 'Daily'){
            $two.show().find("select").attr('disabled', false);
            $one.hide().find("select").attr('disabled', true);
            $three.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
        } else if($(this).val() == 'Monthly'){
            $two.hide().find("select").attr('disabled', true);
            $one.hide().find("select").attr('disabled', true);
            $three.show().find("select").attr("disabled", false);
        } else{
            $one.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
            $two.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
            $three.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It still cannot works. I have modified the code with all three radio button. Let's say if I choose the first radio button, then I enter the number of day and it shows error which the day cannot be blank, same goes to if I choose the second radio button. But if I choose the third radio button and enter the number of day, then it's successful.

Comment: check my update. But the most important is you need to check what params are sending to the server. In your case are sendig twice the same params or nothing. It will depends on how you use the javascript

Comment: Alright, I have solved it. Thanks. It's a drop down list, so $one.hide().find("select").attr("disabled", true); is written. How about if it is a text field, then how should I modify this line of code?

Comment: try this `$one.hide().find("input").attr("disabled", true)`. Be careful, because this solution will work when there is just one `input` or `select`. If there are more, you will need to find the element by a html class